# How to get file name from the url of the file present in firebase storage in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have created a button to download the file from the URL I get from firestore, I need the file name too, is there any way to reference the file using the URL I get?
I saw answers to similar questions but couldn't find the proper solution.

This is the type of **URL** I get

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-app.appspot.com/o/img%2FFileName.pdf?alt=media&token=367f598b-425d-4ce0-be2b-804d2103d69e
```

is there any way to extract the file name from it? or by any reference method?

Comment: How are you getting the download URL? Do you have reference to the file? If you have reference then you can use `.name` property.

Comment: this url get json type? when you upload image at firestorge, you got the url and name. save database ( sql , firestore)

Comment: no, actually I have an admin SDK created in a web browser, from there I am uploading a pdf file, so when after uploading I get the link of the file and store it in firestore document. so I get the link from firestore, there is no reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have the reference to file then you would have to use Regex:

```dart
String getFileName(String url) {
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'.+(\/|%2F)(.+)\?.+'); 
  //This Regex won't work if you remove ?alt...token
  var matches = regExp.allMatches(url);

  var match = matches.elementAt(0);
  print("${Uri.decodeFull(match.group(2)!)}");
  return Uri.decodeFull(match.group(2)!);
}
```

Comment: working fine thank you soo much @Dharmaraj. You have always been solving my problems.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution :
we suppose the url from fireStore :

```
final urlExample = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/example_images%2F12345%2Fexample.jpg?alt=media&token=3ae5accd-ebdc-4fab-a08e-d8d57059614c

String getFileName(String url) {
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
 String fileName = uri.pathSegments.last.split("/").last;
return fileName;
}
final fileNameFromUrl = getFileName(urlExample);
print(fileNameFromUrl); // example.jpg
```